# How to sum negative and positive values separately when using groupby in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum, dataframe

How to sum positive and negative values differently in `pandas` and put them let's say in `positive` and `negative` columns?

I have this dataframe like below:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8), 'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
```

Output is as below:

```
df
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one  0.374156  0.319699
1  bar    one -0.356339 -0.629649
2  foo    two -0.390243 -1.387909
3  bar  three -0.783435 -0.959699
4  foo    two -1.268622 -0.250871
5  bar    two -2.302525 -1.295991
6  foo    one -0.968840  1.247675
7  foo  three  0.482845  1.004697
```

I used the below code to get negatives:

```
df['negative'] = df.groupby('A')['C'].apply(lambda x: x[x<0].sum()).reset_index()]
```

But the problem is when I want to add it to one of `dataframe` columns called `negative` it gives error:

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Again I know what it says that `groupby` has returned more than one column and cannot assign it to `df['negatives']` but I don't know how to solve this part of the problem. I need to have positive col too.

**The desired outcome would be:**

```
    A      Positive   Negative
0  foo     0.374156  -0.319699
1  bar     0.356339  -0.629649
```

What is the right solution to the problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
In [14]:
df.groupby(df['A'])['C'].agg([('negative' , lambda x : x[x < 0].sum()) , ('positive' , lambda x : x[x > 0].sum())])
Out[14]:
     negative   positive
A       
bar -1.418788   2.603452
foo -0.504695   2.880512
```

Comment: When I groupby `A` I expect to see just `foo` and `bar` in the result. Your solution doesn't meet that. I dont need column `B` if it is removed I would be OK with that

Comment: post a sample of your desired result , and it would be better not to generate random data so that we make sure we have the same result

Comment: I've added `The desired outcome would` part to question, please have a look.

Answer (score 6):

You may `groupby` on `A` and `df['C'] > 0`, and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) the result:

```
>>> right = df.groupby(['A', df['C'] > 0])['C'].sum().unstack()
>>> right = right.rename(columns={True:'positive', False:'negative'})
>>> right
C    negative  positive
A                      
bar   -3.4423       NaN
foo   -2.6277     0.857
```

The `NaN` value is because all the `A == bar` rows have negative value for `C`.

if you want to add these to the original frame corresponding to values of `groupby` key, i.e. `A`, it would require a left [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join):

```
>>> df.join(right, on='A', how='left')
     A      B       C       D  negative  positive
0  foo    one  0.3742  0.3197   -2.6277     0.857
1  bar    one -0.3563 -0.6296   -3.4423       NaN
2  foo    two -0.3902 -1.3879   -2.6277     0.857
3  bar  three -0.7834 -0.9597   -3.4423       NaN
4  foo    two -1.2686 -0.2509   -2.6277     0.857
5  bar    two -2.3025 -1.2960   -3.4423       NaN
6  foo    one -0.9688  1.2477   -2.6277     0.857
7  foo  three  0.4828  1.0047   -2.6277     0.857
```

Comment: The final df should be grouped by `A` too. I dont want to group by two criteria, I just want to group by column `A` in your `right` dataframe.

Comment: @AlirezaHos you do not make sense. you need to edit the question and show what is the output you are looking for

Comment: this solution is a way faster then the other one! thx for that